# Why am i getting an error when using union type to separate a different type shape?

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
type Data = {
    isRoot: true
} | {
    isRoot: false
    disabled: boolean
    name: string
}

function nameGetter(d: Data): string | false {
    if (d.isRoot) {
        return false        
    } else {
        return d.name // error here: property 'name' doesnt exist on type Data
    }
}
```

Link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09isRoot%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%09isRoot%3A%20false%0D%0A%09disabled%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%09name%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20nameGetter(d%3A%20Data)%3A%20string%20%7C%20false%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(d.isRoot)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20false%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20d.name%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A

Why is that? While if i use string literal on isRoot

```
type Data = {
    isRoot: 'true'
} | {
    isRoot: 'false'
    disabled: boolean
    name: string
}

function nameGetter(d: Data): string | false {
    if (d.isRoot === 'true') {
        return false        
    } else {
        return d.name
    }
}
```

The code compiles just fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that without `--strictNullChecks`, `if(d.isRoot)` actually fails in *two* possible conditions. It would fall into the `else` block when `d.isRoot` is `false` or when it is `null`. Observe:

```
declare const d: Data;
d.isRoot = null; // throws an error only if --strictNullChecks is enabled
```

You need to enable `--strictNullChecks` in order to ensure that `d.isRoot` cannot also be `null`.

Note also that even without `--strictNullChecks`, the following code works just fine:

```
function nameGetter(d: Data): string | false {
  if (d.isRoot === true) {
    return false        
  } else {
    return d.name
  }
}
```

Comment: `d.isRoot === true` is the solution. Nice one